# IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple

Tags: python

I written down this code:

```
class Apple_Product:
    os = " "
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def check_operating_system(self):
        print("This {} is running {}.".format(name=self.name, os=self.os))

class iPhone(Apple_Product):
    os = "iOS16"

iPhone13Pro = iPhone("iPhone 13 Pro")
iPhone13Pro.check_operating_system()
```

but got this error!
IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class Apple_Product:
    os = " "
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def check_operating_system(self):
        print("This {name} is running {os}.".format(name=self.name, os=self.os))

class iPhone(Apple_Product):
    os = "iOS16"

iPhone13Pro = iPhone("iPhone 13 Pro")
iPhone13Pro.check_operating_system()
```

Your format string and the provided arguments need to be consistent in their convention - either named in both the format string and the arguments, or positional in both the format string and the arguments. The above code is a fix with named parameters, below with positional parameters:

```
class Apple_Product:
    os = " "
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def check_operating_system(self):
        print("This {} is running {}.".format(self.name, self.os))

class iPhone(Apple_Product):
    os = "iOS16"

iPhone13Pro = iPhone("iPhone 13 Pro")
iPhone13Pro.check_operating_system()
```

Answer (score 0):

For `.format`, you pass in your arguments in order like this (not like variable names):

```py
class Apple_Product:
    os = " "
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def check_operating_system(self):
        print("This {} is running {}.".format(self.name, self.os))

class iPhone(Apple_Product):
    os = "iOS16"

iPhone13Pro = iPhone("iPhone 13 Pro")
iPhone13Pro.check_operating_system()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def check_operating_system(self):
    print("This {} is running {}.".format(name=self.name, os=self.os))
```

You are making variable declarations in your format string. You don't need to say name = or os =. Just use:

```
.format(self.name, os)
```